# fopen() does not create or read a file

Tags: php, apache, fopen

I have 2 `.php` files in the same directory: one that asks user for input, and the other one that should add that user input to `.txt file`.
It does not read the file. I tried creating the .txt file first but it's not working anyway.

```
<?php

$name = $_POST["name"];

$handler=fopen("names.txt", 'a');
fwrite($handler,$name);
fclose($handler);

header("Location: submit_name.php");

?>
```

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: What error messages are you getting?

Comment: I'm using Lubuntu based on Ubuntu 14.10

Comment: There is no error message

Comment: Have you checked the value of $name variable?

Comment: Yes, i checked it and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have not permissions to create or read files in that directory. So you have to grant access to `www-data` apache user/group like this :

```
sudo chown www-data -R /var/www/html/
```

And then add yourself to `www-data` group :

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data $USER
```

Comment: Thanks, but help me just a bit more. If my username is ive what do i type.

Comment: You just need to run exactly above commands regardless of user is live or not. Just run them now..

Comment: no hahah you didn't understand what i meant. My username is ive. My name irl is "ive"

Comment: I said just run them. Look `$USER` is a variable which contains your current user name.